# iOS: How to extract thumbnail and metadata from photo file on disk

Tags: ios, avfoundation, metadata, thumbnails, photo

Apple doc here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/capturing_still_and_live_photos/capturing_thumbnail_and_preview_images explains how to capture thubnails.

At the bottom, it says

> If you requested an embedded thumbnail image, that image isn't
> directly accessible from the AVCapturePhoto object—it's embedded in
> the image file data that you get by calling the photo object's
> fileDataRepresentation() method.

Seems impossible to separate the embedded thumbnail from the main photo. So what is the meaning of embedded thumbnail?

I want to save the AVCapturePhoto in JPG and raw DNG (requested embedded thumbnails for both) to App's `Documents` directory (I do not use PhotoKit) and then load it back to a `UIImageView`.

I save a photo like this:

```
if let data = capturePhoto.fileDataRepresentation() {
    data.write(to: documentsPath, options: [])
}
```

And load it back to a `UIImage` like this:

```
if let data = FileManager.default.contents(at: path) {
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

But it will be better to load the embedded thubmail first. If a user clicks to see the large image, load the full imgage file then.

I also want to show the metadata, e.g., GPS location, flash status, ISO, shutter speed etc. I wonder how to do that.

Comment: I believe `AVFoundation` handles metadata only for audio and video formats and that for image formats you use `ImageIO` (Android also divides its metadata APIs into audio+video on the one hand vs images on the other.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AVFoundation`'s `AVAsset` wraps some metadata types, but apparently not EXIF data. If you want the thumbnail you have to use the `CoreGraphics` framework. This function fetches the thumbnail if present, limiting the maximum side length to 512 pixels.

```
public func getImageThumbnail(url: URL) -> CGImage? {
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) else { return nil }
    
    let thumbnailOptions: [String: Any] = [
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform as String: true,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent as String: false, // true will create if thumbnail not present
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize as String: 512
    ]
    return CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, thumbnailOptions as CFDictionary);
}
```

For all the rest of the metadata, you can use `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex` or `CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex`.